# How to get loop first and last value in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, date-range, timedelta, astropy

I want only first and last value I mean 2021-01-30 15:51:47 -2.0665672163030704e-06 and 2021-01-30 15:51:51 -1.0708335011265263e-05 also this code provide date of every second but I want result in every minute.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from astropy.time import Time

start_date_time = datetime(2021, 1, 30, 15, 00, 00)
end_date_time = datetime(2021,1, 30,16,00,00)
time_diff = int((end_date_time - 
start_date_time).total_seconds())

for i in range(time_diff):
    day = (start_date_time + timedelta(0, i))
    dt = Time(day)
    jd =dt.jd
    # print(day,jd)
    eph = swe.calc_ut(jd,2)[0][3]
    if eph < 0:
        print(dt,eph)

Output - 
2021-01-30 15:51:47 -2.0665672163030704e-06
2021-01-30 15:51:48 -4.222647236587894e-06
2021-01-30 15:51:49 -6.384221081802716e-06
2021-01-30 15:51:50 -8.565878651309763e-06
2021-01-30 15:51:51 -1.0708335011265263e-05
```

Comment: instead of range(time_diff) you can put [0, time_diff] and it will give you the first and last value. Since range is giving you the range from 0 to time_diff.

Comment: to clarify, you only want the output where your condition is true (`eph < 0`)? To iterate minutes, you can simply use `timedelta(minutes=i)` in your code.

Comment: yes i want output only when condition true (eph<0) but first and last output

Comment: instead of just printing the results, you could append them to a list, then finally take the first and last element of that list.

Comment: Thankyou @MrFuppes I'm absolute beginners and I'm practicing my self...

Comment: @MrFuppes Once again thankyou very much you are so brilliant

Answer (score 1):

with the comment above, you can specify the keyword in timedelta like this:

```
for i in [0, time_diff]:
    day = (start_date_time + timedelta(minutes=i))
```